# Toggl Reporting API with PHP cURL

Tags: php, rest, curl

I am trying to access the Toggl Reporting API.

I tried following in PHP with cURL, which connects to the API but gives the following error message: 'This method may not be used.' Any light on why this is the case would be useful as I'm very new to webservices. I may be missing something obvious or totally going the wrong way about it, so apologies if this is the case.

```
<?php
$userAgent = 'xxx';//username
$token = 'xxx';//token
$returned_content = get_data('https://toggl.com/reports/api/v2/summary?&workspace_id=[workspaceid]&since=2013-05-19&until=2013-05-20&user_agent=[username here]');
print_r($returned_content);

function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $token.':api_token');
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Edit: I tried a different approach. If I run the following code, I no longer receive any error messages, so the code seems to be executing but I can't print the response to the screen. Is there something specific I need to do to view the output other than print_r?(Toggl API returns JSON). Thanks.

$json = `curl%20-v%20-u%[myapitoken]:api_token%20https://toggl.com/reports/api/v2/weekly?workspace_id=[id]&wsid=282507&since=2012-08-19&until=2013-09-20&user_agent=[user].json`;
print_r($json);

Edit: Finally resolved! Code is as follows:

```
$workspace_id = '[id here]';
$user_agent = '[user agent here]'; // no spaces
$api_token = '[token here]';
$report_url = 'https://toggl.com/reports/api/v2/weekly?user_agent='.$user_agent.'&since=2013-08-01&until=2013-09-01';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_token . ':api_token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $report_url . '&workspace_id=' . $workspace_id);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_encode($result);
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are receiving this message because of `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER == FALSE`.

Try to remove this string from the code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

Maybe I wrong, but I think with this option you are receiving "HTTP 501 Not Implemented" error from the Toggl server, which contains exactly the same message, "This method may not be used."

Comment: Hi, I tried this but I'm getting the same error, this line is in there because it was suggested in the PHP SDK https://github.com/davereid/toggl-php-sdk. Which I can't get working either. Thanks anyway!